# How to add an arrow in UIImageView?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, uiimage

I have to an arrow in a `UIImageView`. it may act like a transparent space in `UIImageView`. a sample image is attached and highlighted with yellow box.
[image]

Comment: Add UIView with rotation transform by M_PI_4

Comment: I think you need to use `Uiview` with Transparent background and set the Arrow and  yellow box inside that `UIView`.

Comment: You question is not clear. Do you want to add arrow or you already have it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use mask,for example you have a 200*100 image
[image]

Code

```
CAShapeLayer * shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
UIBezierPath * bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[bezierPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0,100)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(10,100)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(20,90)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(30, 100)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(200,100)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(200, 0)];
[bezierPath closePath];
shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.CGPath;
self.imageview.layer.mask = shapeLayer;
```

**Note**:The clip part is can still catch touch event or gesture as part of `Imageview`,you may rewrite `pointInside` to Ignore touch event

**Edit About how it works**

You just need to create any shape you like ,the about code I just create a shape like this,then use this shape to set mask

[image]

So,if you want make a right arrow,just create a shape like this

```
CAShapeLayer * shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
UIBezierPath * bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[bezierPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0,100)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(170,100)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(180,90)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(190, 100)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(200,100)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(200, 0)];
[bezierPath closePath];
shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.CGPath;
```

Shape screenshot

[image]

**So,what you need is**

- Figure out what shape you want(the outline mask shape)
- Use bezierPath to draw
- Set mask

Comment: Also, you will need to set background to the UIImageView. If you not set, there will be a black hole.

Comment: It works but can you please define me the functionality of this line [bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(200, 200)];
infact my image is not covering full width, other than that it working

Comment: can you please explain what these lines are doing, cz now i have to place this arrow on the right side of image

Comment: Sorry,did not see the comment.Please see the update words